# Webhook event invoice.paid not triggering in stripe after invoice is paid

Tags: stripe-payments, stripes

I'm currently working with two distinct Stripe accounts, one for development and one for staging. In the development environment, when I initiate a future subscription and it becomes active, Stripe generates an invoice paid event. However, this event is not being triggered in the staging account. Additionally, there are variations in the events being generated between these two accounts.

Since the staging account belongs to our client, I don't have direct access to it for debugging purposes. If anyone has any suggestions or insights to offer, I would greatly appreciate it. I'm open to exploring any suggestions to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The webhook endpoint on that client's account is likely not configured to listen to `invoice.paid` Events which might be why you are not receiving it. What you can do is use the List Events [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/list) and pass `type: 'invoice.paid'` to confirm whether an Event is generated or not on that account. If it is then you can ask your client to ensure they configure their webhook endpoint properly, or you can use the Update WebhookEndpoint [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/webhook_endpoints/update) and pass the right set of Event types in `enabled_events`.

Otherwise, you will need to access the account's Dashboard to look at its configuration and figure out what could be different with your own account.

Comment: It was configured properly. The issue was with Stripe itself. The event was firing after two to three days. Had to change our code's logic to cope up with the situation.